# Create a Paypal donate button using a smart button with options to choose price or fill own price

Tags: jquery, paypal

When i input my own desired price paypal payment platform pops up fine, but my problem is when i click on options prices paypal seems not to detect the price value.
This is what i have done below. When i click on those individual prices. paypal doesnt seem get the value of price. The value appears in the input field but its not recognized by paypal unless if i enter the value i want manually.

Please i need to this, am working on a project. This needs to work dynamically. is there something am doing wrong with javascript? Please tell me. Also tell me a better way to do this.

```
       <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center">  
       <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/digitalassets/c/website/marketing/apac/C2/logos-buttons/optimize/26_Blue_PayPal_Pill_Button.png" alt="PayPal" /></table>

           
<h4 class="text-style-news">Paypal Payment Platform</h4>
<button id="Paypal1" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="margin-right: 15px;">$10</button>
<button id="Paypal2" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="margin-right: 15px;">$20</button>
<button id="Paypal3" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="margin-right: 15px;">$50</button>
<button id="Paypal4" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">$100</button> 

  <label style="float: left;" for="amount" class="mb-2"><p class="support-p"><strong>Any Amount*</strong></p></label>
             <br> <br>        
    <input type="number" id="amount" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="in $USD" onchange="Pay()">
              <br>
 <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>    
    <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
        <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD">          
          </script>

<script>
        var amount = 0;
        function Pay() {
            // body...
       amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
        }
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({
            // Set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: amount
                               }
                            }]
                        });
                  },
            // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    alert('Donation completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                   location.replace("https://www.example.com/completed_success.php");
                });
            }

        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
<script>
    $("#Paypal1").click(function () {
    $("#amount").val("10");   
});  
    $("#Paypal2").click(function () {
    $("#amount").val("20");   
});  
    $("#Paypal3").click(function () {
    $("#amount").val("50");   
});
   
    $("#Paypal4").click(function () {
    $("#amount").val("100");   
});
   </script>
```

Comment: Would you mind accepting my working answer if I have helped you with question. Let me know.

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your answer, I was away from home. So sorry am replying late. but I think am still stocked with it. It seems PayPal sees those values as a string. Still having same issue, only works when I input values manually. How do I use parseInt() ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to get value as a number. Please see the `Pay` function.  `amount = parseInt($('#amount').val())`

Comment: I will do this give you feedback later. In case I still run into problem what else can I do to the code?

Comment: I found out the what the issue is. You are not calling `Pay()` function at all when you click on buttons like custom amounts. The reason its only working for manually input is that you have `onchange="Pay()"` in your input. I have added `Pay()` function in your click function as well so it gets called when you click on buttons as well as you when you type the amount manually. I have edited my answer below.

Comment: Also. I have added a full working demo with paypal working perfectly with correct amount added. See my updated answer for `jsfiddle` demo link.

Comment: Thanks bro I think you just saved my life. Thank you thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplified your `code` by using *one* `click` function and having [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) attributes in your HTML buttons also adding one `class` to your button which will used to call click events.

We can just assign `data-id` to each button with respective amounts and when the buttons are clicked we use jQuery `data` to get `id` and the value assigned to the `id` which will be amount.

Also, i would rec-emend using `jQuery` only or plain `JS` only. Its not preferred to mixed up both so there is no confusion.

To get the amount you can simply use `.val()` function in `Pay()` function.

I would also suggest using [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) which is the function to convert a `string` to a `number` (integer). I believe paypal expects a number as an `amount` and not a string value.

> **Full working demo with paypal:** https://jsfiddle.net/alwayshelping/ncxd26v7/2/

Run snippet below to see it working. (You can add the pay-pal configuration back into code and as the snippet here block it if i add it.)

```js
//One click function to get data (amount)
$(".Paypal").click(function() {
  $('#amount').val($(this).data('id'))
  
  //Call pay function again so the value is update as well for paypal.
  Pay()
});


var amount = 0;

function Pay() {

  //Get amount 
  amount = parseInt($('#amount').val()) //Get value as int with parseInt
  console.log(amount)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center">
  <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/digitalassets/c/website/marketing/apac/C2/logos-buttons/optimize/26_Blue_PayPal_Pill_Button.png" alt="PayPal" /></table>

<h4 class="text-style-news">Paypal Payment Platform</h4>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger Paypal" data-id="10" style="margin-right: 15px;">$10</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger Paypal" data-id="20" style="margin-right: 15px;">$20</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger Paypal" data-id="30" style="margin-right: 15px;">$50</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger Paypal" data-id="100">$100</button>

<label style="float: left;" for="amount" class="mb-2"><p class="support-p"><strong>Any Amount*</strong></p></label>
<br> <br>
<input type="number" id="amount" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="in $USD" onchange="Pay()">
<br>
<!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
```